# Get id of selected item in ng-option

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

I would like to get the id of the selected item but `console.log` display *undefined*.

**View**

```
 <select ng-change="test()" ng-model="selectedone" ng-options="item.id as item.pseudo for item in friends"></select>
```

**Controller**

```
  $scope.test = function(){
        console.log($scope.selectedone);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know what you did wrong, OP.  It's working for me.  See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvh8djp2/

Comment: I'm doing this with ionic i don't know if it matter

Comment: Your code snippet worked for me, maybe your array is malformed? Could you make a fiddle to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: i manage to solve this, see my answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is the running code:

view:

```
 <select ng-change="test(selectedId)" ng-model="selectedId" ng-options="id.id as id.pseudo for id in idList"> </select>
```

controller:

```
  $scope.test = function(selectedId) {
            alert(selectedId);
        }
```